# Excel 2013 Fuzzy Lookup to find near-duplicate text

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate, lookup

I have a list of captions with a large number of near-duplicates. For example:

- Birthday for Her
- For Her Birthday
- Birthday - For Her
- For Her / Birthday

I was looking into Fuzzy Lookup as a way of highlighting these near-duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I was looking into Fuzzy Lookup as a way of highlighting these near-duplicates

The Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel performs fuzzy matching of textual data in Excel.

---

#### Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel

> The Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel was developed by Microsoft Research
> and performs fuzzy matching of textual data in Microsoft Excel.
>
> It can be used to identify fuzzy duplicate rows within a single table
> or to fuzzy join similar rows between two different tables. The
> matching is robust to a wide variety of errors including spelling
> mistakes, abbreviations, synonyms and added/missing data.
>
> For instance, it might detect that the rows “Mr. Andrew Hill”, “Hill,
> Andrew R.” and “Andy Hill” all refer to the same underlying entity,
> returning a similarity score along with each match.
>
> While the default configuration works well for a wide variety of
> textual data, such as product names or customer addresses, the
> matching may also be customized for specific domains or languages.

Source [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011)

---

#### Any suggestions on the Similarity Threshold configuration?

[Performing Fuzzy Lookups in Excel](http://k2e.com/tech-update/tips/431-tip-fuzzy-lookups-in-excel) has some hints on Similarity Threshold configuration.

Comment: My table of captions is a single column in alphabetical order. So I want to compare the table to itself to find the near duplicates. Most of the examples I have seen online use two different tables. is there an example on how to configure the Lookup to compare a single table to itself?

Comment: Not that I know know of. Have you tried duplicating the table in a second column and then comparing the original to the duplicate?

Comment: that may be the trick!  I will try that and let you know.  Any suggestions on the Similarity Threshold configuration? Thanks!

Comment: Searching for "Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel examples" gives some links you could investigate.

Comment: http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/431-tip-fuzzy-lookups-in-excel has some hints on Similarity Threshold configuration.