# how to find and highlight similar texts in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, highlighting

I am not pro in Excel. I have an excel table that I need to find similar values and highlight the the remaining texts.

I have read some questions here but it was not helpful in my case.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,
Lili

Comment: Answer for your question is far beyond scope of this site. At first it's unclear, what similar means for you? After answering that it probably would require complex programming and as such it's off-topic, as here we answer well defined single question instead of providing entire solutions.

Comment: To build off of what Mate said, some examples of your data, as well as what steps you've already tried to take would help quite a bit. Your question is too vague as it stands right now. It's possible there's a formulaic answer, conditional formatting, VBA scripting, etc. Screenshots of your worksheet, a clear description of what you're trying to accomplish (what terms are you trying to match), the desired outcome, and what you've already tried will help us help you.

Comment: Revelant?: [Excel 2013 Fuzzy Lookup to find near-duplicate text](http://superuser.com/q/926382)

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Conditional Formatting`.  The `Conditional Formatting` option is on the Home Tab in Excel in the `Styles` section.  [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) is a Support.Office.com tutorial on some of the options you have for conditional formatting.